# How assign a value to auto scroll attribute with a model, ui-routing angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have the autoscroll value in "true" after the page load, why? because if I fix the value before, the autoscroll is applied, and I only want change the value to true when a user click some link.

Here is the code:

**view:**

```
<div class= "detail ng-fadeIn" data-ui-view="" autoscroll="{{consultation.autoscroll}}" dynamic-content></div>
```

**controller:**

```
vm.autoscroll = "false"
```

The problem is that I try this, I get this error: 
**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{consultation.autoscroll}}] starting at [{consultation.autoscroll}}]**

Comment: you don't need the `{{ }}` in this case.

Comment: @Claies true! a big carelessness. Thank you!